# static arm64 iOS library does not link in a tvOS project

Tags: tvos

I have a static fat library, which contains the architecture arm64, that can be linked in a project for iOS.
However, when I try to use this library in a tvOS project I have the following link error:

```
 "... building for tvOS, but linking in object file built for iOS, for architecture arm64"
```

I am not sure if I can reuse arm64 libraries, which work properly in iOS projects, in a tvOS project or perhaps I will have to create an arm64 library from a tvOS project (TV static library).

Comment: It depends on what system frameworks the static library code is using.  Not everything is available for tvOS.

Answer (score 2):

For Xcode 7, object files and static libraries are marked with both the platform and the minimum version that they're designed for.

You'll have to build a separate library for each platform (and each platform target would need to link against the static library specifically built for that platform).

Trying to build a library that supports multiple platforms would run contrary to app thinning techniques such as slicing:

> Slicing is the process of creating and delivering variants of the app bundle for different target devices. A variant contains only the executable architecture and resources that are needed for the target device.

Comment: Yes, I have realised about that using the command: otool -lv <mylibrary.a> | grep LC_VERSION  whose answer is cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_TVOS